# MVC Web Api routing Multiple Gets that have different parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, get, routes, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

So I have three different Get actions:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(){
//get all entries
}

public IHttpActionResult Get(int id){
//get an entry based on an ID
}

public IHttpActionResult Get(int page =0, int pageSize = 2){
//Pagination:get entries by pages of 2 entries
}
```

At first I was working with the two first methods it was fine using this routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default",
        "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "project", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

After adding the third Get action that has two parameters, it started returning an exception: Multiple actions were found that match the request. By the way, I was sending the page parameter as a query string like this: `api/project/?page=0`. 
I do understand that the two last actions are the source of the problem and the router can't decide which one to match but I haven't been able to come up with the right routing function.
Although, I have used attribute routing which kind of solves the issue: Route["api/project/{page:int}/{pageSize:int}"] I am more interested in using the old routing way to solve this issue.
I apologize for the lengthy message and thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int page =0, int pageSize = 2){
//Pagination:get entries by pages of 2 entries
}
```

for

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int? page, int pageSize = 2){
//Pagination:get entries by pages of 2 entries
}
```

Comment: Thx for the quick answer mate, sadly I did not work :( I think I need to focus on making another routing function specific for the paging action :/

Comment: you can use only one route, with id, page and pagesize as optional. 
(int? id, int? page, int? pageSize)

Comment: hmm I don't think that is feasible since one of the Get only retrieves one object at a time by id. And the pagination returns a page with a few objects at a time.